# Where can I find all of git's color options?

Tags: git, git-config

I want to customise my git colour output.

1. Where can I find a list of all options for which I can specify the colour?
2. Where can I find all colours and modifiers that I can set an option to?

Eg, where can I find a complete list of options like:

```
color.ui
color.branch.current
color.branch.upstream
color.diff.new
color.diff.newMovedAlternative
color.diff-highlight.oldNormal
color.grep.match
color.interactive.help
color.status.untracked
```

And a list of colors and modifiers like:

```
blue green red
bold dim blink strike no-bold
```

Comment: See http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/gitcolors.html and [git help config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: You can also take a look at this [repo](https://gist.github.com/rab/4067067)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this is controlled by `git config`.

The list of colors is available at [color](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color). As explained there, different consoles support different colors. For example in Windows you don't see exactly the same colors in `PowerShell`, in `cmd`, or in `mingw64` which uses a bash port for Windows.

There are a lot of colors that can be configured. For example, the colors used when you run `git status` are [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorstatusltslotgt). But there are much more colors, for example for `diff`, `grep`, `merge`, `blame`... They all have default configurations which I recommend you not to change unless necessary, so that anyone using your `git` environment, or you using another environment, always see the standard colors.

If you run `git config --get-regexp color` you can see the current colors configured in your config files, `.gitconfig`, but, as explained above, these are only the colors that you have explicitly changed. See the help for the different existing git configuration files: local, global, system (repository, user, machine).